# How to get bison grammar rule for tokens

Tags: bison, bisonc++

Let's say I have the following rules:

```
rule1 : TOKEN rule2 TOKEN { printf("Found TOKEN\n") ; }

rule2 : ATOKEN { printf("Found ATOKEN\n") ; }
```

Here, the output will be the following:

```
Found ATOKEN
Found TOKEN
```

Because `rule2` will be reduced first. Is there any way I can print something as soon as I get `TOKEN`?

**N.B** I know I can do that from the scanner when it matches the TOKEN, but I need to print it from bison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bison allows actions to be within a rule (known as [mid-rule actions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Using-Mid_002dRule-Actions.html#Using-Mid_002dRule-Actions)).

In your example they could be used like this:

```
rule1 : TOKEN { printf("Found TOKEN 1\n"); } rule2 TOKEN { printf("Found TOKEN\n") ; }

rule2 : ATOKEN { printf("Found ATOKEN\n") ; }
```

but you should read the documentation carefully to see if this has the semantic effect that you desire.

Comment: For now it's working as I want it to. I will check the semantic errors later. Thanks for the answer.